# A question about complex convergent series.

Tags: complex-analysis

Say the complex series $P(z)$ has the radius of convergence $S=|z|<R$. My book says

> at every $a\in S$, we can select a polynomial $P_m(a)$ such that $|P_m(a)-P(a)|<\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is any arbitrary positive real number. Here $P_m(a)$ comprises of the first $m$ terms of $P(a)$.

In other words, $P(z)$ is uniformly convergent on $S$. I don't understand why that is true. Can $m$ not be different for every point in $S$? All we can say for $P(z)$ is that it converges at every point in $S$. It does not have to converge to the same limit, and not even at the same speed!

Edit: My book says that we can choose such an $m$ only for values of $z$ not approaching the circle of convergence. I don't see how such a restriction allows us to do this either. We still have an infinite number of different $m$'s, and hence finding a "maximum" may be impossible as the set of $m$'s may be unbounded.

Thank you.

Comment: Seems a little confusing that you are using $S$ both for the radius and  for the subset.

Comment: @user99680- The radius is $R$. The whole region $|z|<R$ is $S$

Comment: I see, sorry for my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a power series is not uniformly convergent, but it is locally uniformly convergent.

Indeed, let $R>0$ be the radius of convergence and assume for simplicity that the power series is centered at $x=0$.

Choose $S < R$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. As $S$ lies in the circle of convergence, e have absolute convergence at $S$, I.e. there exists $N$ with 
$\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} |a_n| S^n < \varepsilon$.

For $|x| < S$ we get

$\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} |a_n x^n| \leq \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} |a_n| S^n < \varepsilon$.

Comment: My point is that the value of $n$ may be different at different points in the radius of convergence. But the book says we can choose the same $n$ for all points in the radius of convergence.

Comment: My proof above shows that for $S < R$ fixed(!), you can choose the same(!) $N$ for all $|x| < S$.

In general it is not possible to choose the same $N$ for all $|x| < R$, because the limit function would then have to be bounded (among others) on the open circle of convergence. This is for example not the case for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the circle of convergence is centered at $0$. If $S <R$, say $R-S=a>0$ , consider the closed disk $D(0, S+a/2)$. This is compact, and contains $D(0,S)$. Then the series converges uniformly in $D(0, S+a/2)$ by compactness of $ D(0,S+a/2)$ and so it also converges uniformly in the smaller disk $D(0,S)$.